# decode qrcode using zxing

Tags: java, zxing

I'm trying to decode a qrcode from an image, but zxing return notfound exception
The same image, scanned with my mobile from the screen is succesfully decode: how to improve the quality of this file to permit to have it decoded by zxing (or other java library)
I've no reputation, so I cannot upload image: the sample image is at the address
Previous link edited

I'm trying to decode it with the following code

```
Reader xReader = new QRCodeReader();

BufferedImage dest = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(dest);

BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Vector<BarcodeFormat> barcodeFormats = new Vector<>();
barcodeFormats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

HashMap<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new HashMap<>(3);
decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, barcodeFormats);

decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

Result result = null;
result = xReader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the noise. Don't dither to 1-bit monochrome, or, apply a light blur filter.

Comment: Where I dither to monochrome?
I don't know how to do it: I've never managed images under java before.
Could you help me with an example?

Comment: I've studied and searched a little about blurring an image, and it worked!!
Thanks